# Passenger Error: No such file or directory - config/environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, ubuntu, passenger

I am trying to deploy my first rails app onto an Ubuntu/Apache/Passenger server, deployed with Capistrano. I have setup a virtual host to point to a directory where all my rails apps will live:

Here is my virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName rails.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias rails.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/rails.mydomain.com
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/rails.mydomain.com>
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride all
            Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </Directory>

    # PassengerAppRoot /var/www/vhosts/rails.mydomain.com
    RailsBaseURI /myappname
    # RailsBaseURI /myappname2
    # RailsBaseURI /myappname3

    Include /etc/apache2/production-expires.conf
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/rails.mydomain.com-access_log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/rails.mydomain.com-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Upon loading the rails app (rails.mydomain.com/myappname) i get:

```
Error message:
     No such file or directory - config/environment.rb
Exception class:
    Errno::ENOENT
Application root:
    /var/www/vhosts/rails.mydomain.com
```

The config/environment.rb is there, I verified it's existence through SSH after running cap deploy.

So what am I missing, i feel like something is not pointing properly, you can see the Application root is pointing to my /rails.mydomain.com folder, not the actual /rails.mydomain.com/myappname folder.

Comment: This could be a permissions issue. Sometimes Apache requires access to the entire folder tree in order to get to your file, i.e. it needs to be able to have permissions for `/var/www/vhosts` and not just `/rails.mydomain.com` Just a thought.

Comment: @FareeshVijayarangam I believe this is already allowed, I am no apache expert... but in the /vhosts i have a default file which I think allows this (like I said, no expert)

Comment: Your `DocumentRoot` needs to point to the `public` folder of your rails app I believe

Comment: So how would i do that running multiple apps?
I would need to create a virtual host for each individual app in my /rails folder, and that virtual host's documentroot needs to point to the app folder?

Answer (score 1):

Did you symlink myappname to the public directory of your app?

```
ln -s /path/to/the/myappname/public/ /var/www/vhosts/rails.mydomain.com/myappname
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Passenger docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html) (see "3.1. Deploying to a virtual host's root"), you need to set your DocumentRoot to your app's public directory.  Try this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/rails.mydomain.com/public
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/rails.mydomain.com/public>
            Allow from all
            Options +MultiViews
</Directory>
```

Comment: I've read this documentation a few times... I guess I just don't understand how to deploy to a non-root, my virtual host's root is just where multiple apps with live. My folder would actually be `/var/www/vhosts/rails.mydomain.com/myappname/public` - this is where i get lost